# Saving a large amount of data

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am developing an app and I want to save large amount of user's data. I tried **SQLite**, **Room** and **Realm** databases but:

1. Realm has a limit on storing data (16 mb per column).
2. Room and SQLite are not working with strings bigger than 5 mb.

I tested all 3 databases and got errors while saving a big json string (I am using Gson to encode user's data to string).

I don't want to use serialization because it's very slow.

Can anyone tell me if there is a solution to store large amount of data?

Comment: 16 Mb per column looks huge, this information is a string? 16Mb string will never fit inside the screen, can I ask you what is this string storing?

Comment: First of all sql is bad idea to store blobs ... but SQLite has no such limitation ... the limitation is CursorWindow size ... but obviously you can obtain data with multiple `SELECT SUBSTRING(column, start,  end)` statments where `end - start` < 5MB ... **the right solution is to store data in the file and in db only the path to it**

Comment: why do you want to save that much data in a column? Why not write the user data to the apps data folders?

Comment: I am storing some base64 encoded images, notes, backups, audio

Comment: write those images, notes, backups, audios as files in internal storage.. and keep their path in db as selvin suggested

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, that seems like a good idea

Comment: @rafid059 Thanks, I will try to do this

Comment: @TopAdStudio What I found mostly strange is your 'I don't want to use serialization because its slow' statement while using Gson, which is slow as a snail due to heavy usage of reflection. Also a 16Mb JSON String is a heavy task to parse which should be avoided at all costs